# How to render terraform data when using a count

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-template-file

I was using a count for creating multiple AWS task_definitions that should be executed by an AWS step function.
The task_definition required a `data "template_file" "task_definition" {` section to be able to fill the template data.
Then I needed to render the template data for multiple definitions at a time and I was blocked by an error looking like this:

```
The "count" value depends on resource attributes that cannot be determined until apply, so Terraform cannot predict how many instances will be created. To work around this, use the -target argument to first apply only the resources that the for_each depends on.
```

Here's the initial code:

```
data "template_file" "task_definition" {
  count    = length(var.task_container_command)
  template = file("./configs/file.json")
  vars = {
    task = module.ecs[count.index].task_definition
  }
}

module "step_function" {
  count  = length(var.task_container_command)
  source = "path"
  region                    = var.region
  name                      = "${var.step_function_name}-${count.index}"
  definition_file           = data.template_file.task_definition.rendered
}
```

The point here is that I can't render task_definition because these are not known by terraform yet before the apply. I wasn't able to use the `-target` argument either because I wanted to make the change in code and not in my deployment pipeline. Meaning when you try to do a `terraform plan` on the `definition_file`, the error will pop up.
Solution is below.

Answer (score 3):

What worked was to decouple the use of the `count` from the `.rendered` argument by doing this:

```
data "template_file" "task_definition" {
  count    = length(var.task_container_command)
  template = file("./configs/file.json")
  vars = {
    task = module.ecs[count.index].task_definition
  }
}

resource "local_file" "foo" {
  count    = length(var.task_container_command)
  content  = element(data.template_file.task_definition.*.rendered, count.index)
  filename = "task-definition-${count.index}"
}

module "step_function" {
  count  = length(var.task_container_command)
  source = "path"
  region                    = var.region
  name                      = "${var.step_function_name}-${count.index}"
  definition_file           = local_file.foo[count.index].filename
}
```

Now your data is rendered in the resource called "foo" here and then passed to the step_function module so the `terraform plan` already knows what's inside your variable. The content element of foo acts like a loop to render each task_definition that I've created using a different filename to avoid duplicates.

Hope this helped :)

Comment: One tip: there is now a built-in function, `templatefile`: https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/templatefile.html.